# Running a shell command from a variable in a shell script

Tags: shell

I am programming a game using Linux.

I have shell script:

```
//run.sh    
A="string1"
B="string2"
C="string3"

COMMAND_LINE="python ../file.py \"$A\" \"$B\" --flag1 ../file.txt --flag2 $C"
echo "$COMMAND_LINE"
$COMMAND_LINE
```

//note the ' \" ' are intentionally

I want shell to run the command in COMMAND_LINE.
for some reason the command does not work, but if i take the string that was created and stored in COMMAND_LINE(the string that was echoed) and run it through the shell, the program works fine.

any suggestions?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The embedded quotes in `COMMAND_LINE` are treated as literal characters; they do not quote the value of `$A` when `$COMMAND_LINE` is expanded. There really isn't a good, safe way to execute the value of a variable as a command in a POSIX shell.

If you are using `bash` or another shell that supports arrays, you can try

```
options=( ../file.py "$A" "$B" --flag1 ../file.txt --flag2 $C )
echo "python ${options[@]}"
python "${options[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd pretty much have to use one of:

```
eval $COMMAND_LINE
sh -c "$COMMAND_LINE"
```

but in general, that's a fraught and dangerous process.  If you're in charge of the complete string in `$COMMAND_LINE` (no input from the user), and with the values shown, it is safe enough.  If the user can introduce their own shell script notation into any of the variables (`$A`, `$B` or `$C`, for example), then you are in for a world of hurt.